# why convert string to a file like object when it is an object itself

Tags: python-2.7

I've heard everything is an object in python. If it is so, why convert a string (which can be assumed an object residing in python memory) to be coverted to a file like object using some module like StringIO or CStringIO?

Answer (score 1):

Because some functions were written assuming they'd receive an opened file as an argument.

```
def example_process_file_contents(opened_file):
    # Skip first line, it's a header
    opened_file.readline()

    # Process the rest line by line
    for line in opened_file:
        do_something_with(line)
```

Now let's say you don't have the data in a file, but in a string in memory. If you put that string in a StringIO object, you now have an object that behaves exactly like an opened file object (hence **file like** object) and you can pass it into that function.

Beats writing the string to a file, opening the file for reading, and passing that...

Answer (score 1):

Just because everything is an object does not mean everything is the *same* kind of object (class).

A `String` object supports certain methods -- like `uppercase()` to return a version of it converted it to uppercase, etc.

A file-like-object (eg a `StringIO`) supports different methods,
like reading off the first few bytes, and fast appending.

#### Example

An example I spent most of today dealing with:
Swift [client.put_object](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-swiftclient/swiftclient.html#swiftclient.client.put_object) takes:

> **contents** – a string, a file-like object or an iterable to read object data from; if None, a zero-byte put will be done.

I want to upload some binary data, from memory.
In my case it is a HDF5 object.
But that is not, a `string`, nor is it a `file-like object`.
It is iterable, but it is not an iterable of `string` or `file-like object` (which is what the docs fail to mention as a requirement).

It is not a compatible type.

I save the HDF5 object, to a `StringIO` and the I upload that with `Swift`,  as that is a type of object Swift can work with.
I can't save it to a string, because the Save method does not create strings -- it is set up to save only to a file-like object -- in that it is intended to be used on a file.

Different classes are different.

#### Consider also: [The Codeless Code, Case 6](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/6).

In that parable, the objects in question are different forms of Nothing.
An empty List, and a Null.
But they are not the same nothing.
A jar that is empty of paper, is not the same as a jar that is empty of scorpions.